# Web2py: got an unexpected keyword argument when controller function called

Tags: web2py

In db.py

`articles_service = Service()`

In controller.py

```
def call():
    """
    exposes services. for example:
    http://..../[app]/articles/call/jsonrpc
    decorate with @services.jsonrpc the functions to expose
    supports xml, json, xmlrpc, jsonrpc, amfrpc, rss, csv
    """
    return articles_service()

@articles_service.json
def article_search():
    # do something with request.post_vars
```

Making an URL call to `app/controller/article_search` throws:

`TypeError: article_search() takes no arguments (1 given)`

This has happened after upgrading Web2py from `web2py v2.14.6` to `v2.18.2`

I think I was perhaps relying on a bug in the earlier Web2py release which has since been closed.

If I add a parameter to my controller function e.g., `def article_search(param)` an exception is thrown:

`TypeError: article_search() got an unexpected keyword argument` followed by a dict (holding the request.post_vars).

Full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~jupiter1351/t1.416461603777157393/gluon/restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
    exec(ccode, environment)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~jupiter1351/t1.416461603777157393/applications/jupiter/controllers/articles.py", line 115, in <module>
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~jupiter1351/t1.416461603777157393/gluon/globals.py", line 421, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~jupiter1351/t1.416461603777157393/applications/jupiter/controllers/articles.py", line 114, in call
    return articles_service()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~jupiter1351/t1.416461603777157393/gluon/tools.py", line 5366, in __call__
    return self.serve_json(request.args[1:])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~jupiter1351/t1.416461603777157393/gluon/tools.py", line 5050, in serve_json
    s = self.call_service_function(self.json_procedures[args[0]], *args[1:], **d)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~jupiter1351/t1.416461603777157393/gluon/tools.py", line 5391, in call_service_function
    return f(*a, **b)
TypeError: article_search() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. What is the relevance of `openings_service`?

Comment: added full stacktrace to q.

Comment: openings_service was an error when I wrote the question. The correct value is articles_service. Used as a decorator that will return data to the caller in json format. It may or not be relevant to this question but, Web2py users may know if something about such decorator could be tripping me up